# Project level `build.gradle` file not containing the code to add the firebase plugin

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to setup firebase for the first time and following a tutorial.
I have to this to the project level `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
  // ...

  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false

}
```

But when I tried to access `build.gradle` file, this is all I see:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I try to add the code as it is to the build file, the app crashes...
Can anyone help me out?